# Kendo UI multiselect text of selected values

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, kendo-ui

i have a problem. Right now I have a normal Kendo-Ui Multiselect which doesn´t work.

You can choose those values: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKuf1.png)

The problem is the following. When you select one or more values, the name of the selected values wouldn´t shown in the input field. There is only an empty box. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqKOo.png)

Here is one part of my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Assigned Attributes</label>
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <select id="dropdownAttributes"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And the other one:

```
var days = [
    { text: "First", value: "1" },
    { text: "Second", value: "2" },
    { text: "Third", value: "3" },
    { text: "Fourth", value: "4" },
    { text: "Fifth", value: "5" }
];

$("#dropdownAttributes").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: days,                  
    height: 200,
    filter: "contains"
});
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: When I run your code in the kendo ui dojo, I don't get the same problem. My guess is that you have css which is affecting the display of selected values. Inspect the element with the browser dev tools to see what rules have been applied. You can switch rules off from there to determine what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you @NigelK! The tip was exactly right. In the base.css was defined for this button that no text should be displayed. Now it works!